# Weak convergence of product of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

> Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are random variables defined on the same
>   probability space. Prove that if $X_n$ converges weakly to a random
>   variable $X$ and $Y_n$ converges weakly to a constant $c$, then $X_n
>  Y_n$ converges to $cX$.

I'm new to weak convergence, and I've recently learned about theorems like Prokhorov's Theorem. I'm studying for an exam, and this is one problem that I have been stuck on for some time now. I saw a similar question on this website, but it was different since the convergence was not weak convergence.

I would greatly appreciate your help in solving this problem as I revise for my exams since I have been stuck for quite some time now.

Comment: This is Slutsky's Theorem.

Comment: But isn't it different since I'm dealing with weak convergence?

Comment: Weak convergence to a constant is equivalent to convergence in probability to that constant.